# How to read SVG file for ImageView from assets folder Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, assets

when i tried to read SVG files, it return error :

`E/Drawable: Unable to decode stream: android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.`

but  when i convert the files into PNG, it works fine. Why is it?

Here is my Kotlin Code :

```
        val tImage = dialog.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.testImageV)
        val am = activity.assets
        val files = am.list("images")

        val drawables : ArrayList<Drawable> = arrayListOf()

        files.forEach{
            drawables.add(Drawable.createFromStream(am.open("images/$it"),
                null))
        }

        tImage.setImageDrawable(drawables[0])
```

Yes, i put the files inside folder `images`, a subfolder of `assets`

**NOTE :** I know how to save SVG within the `drawable` (converted to XML), but is there any way to save it inside `assets` folder? `assets` do not have access to `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: PNG is supported. JPG is supported. SVG not.

Comment: Are you talking about an *actual* SVG file (`.svg`), or an SVG that have been converted to a VectorDrawable?  If you mean an SVG, then Android does not support SVG files natively. You would need to use a third party SVG renderer. For example, AndroidSVG, or svg-android.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau is it possible to save converted SVG in the `assets` folder? the problem is `assets` do not have access to `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`. I need to get all of the files inside the folder, thus i have to store it in a certain specific folder